# Generate java classes with JAXB2 in another maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jaxb, spring-ws

Can someone please help me with my problem?

I have two maven projects A and B. 
I want project A to contain all my model classes and in project B i'm creating a contract-first web service with Spring WS. So in project B, I use maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate classes from my schema. It happens that the generate classes in my webservice project (project A) are identical to the ones in my model project (project A) (with no XML annotations).

Because i don't want to have duplicate classes in my web service project (project B), i decided to make this project depends on the model project (project A) and what i want next is, not anymore generate classes to the webservice project but to the model project (project A).

Do you think there isn't another way to do this ?
Can someone please help me doing this if it's possible?

### Project A

```
package project.a;

public class Client {
  //...
}
```

### Project B

#### Class

```
package project.b;

public class Compte {
  //This class manipulates a Client object
  //...
}
```

#### JAXB2 Maven Plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>xjc</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>xjc</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
    <packageName>project.a</packageName>
    <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/schemas</schemaDirectory>
    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
  </configuration>
<plugin>
```

#### Schema

```
<element name="client">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <!--  -->
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

#### Project B spring bean configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
  <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
  <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/project/" />
</bean>
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
  <property name="contextPath" value="project.a"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: is there something wrong with how it's done now?

Comment: When a try to run project B i have an error like `org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class project.b.Compte nor any of its super class is known to this context.` I updated my question and added part of my Spring bean configuration file

Comment: can you paste a bit more code from both of your classes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to recreate model classes again. Just place them in Project A and then import those beans into Project B as:

```
    <import resource="classpath:projectABeanDefinitionFile.xml" />
```

Assuming you are implementing/going to @XmlRootElement on Compte class (else suggest to go through a tutorial like [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/)),
then change project B file as:

```
    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
      <property name="classesToBeBound" value="project.b.Compte"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me but this doesn't work for me. Because i had to deal with delays i will go for the duplicate classes way and try later to optimize. Thank you too @soulcheck